# Google Realtime API (or its functionality) for Android?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api, google-drive-android-api

Some questions have asked this already:
[Is Google Drive RealTime API for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15864500/is-google-drive-realtime-api-for-android), and [Does the Google Drive realtime API support Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15592494/does-the-google-drive-realtime-api-support-android)

However, it was described by one commenter two years ago as a "high priority" for Google, and I know that the Drive API capabilities for Android have greatly increased, however, there seems to be no Google documentation I can find on the topic.

So what are the options for using the Realtime API, or collaboratively interacting on realtime files in Android?